# What is the Correct 'pf' Syntax for an 'iptables' Port Redirection Rule

Tags: macos, network, firewall

I am looking to implement a rule like the following `iptables` rule on my Mac, to redirect traffic from my development workstation (hosting a development copy of a Ruby on Rails project) to another host on my LAN that is running the PostgreSQL database server. *Without having to change the `database.yml` config file on my local copy of the code*:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --destination-port 5432 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.104:5432
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some brief googling, I came up with this, which seems to work great.

```
echo "rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 5432 -> 192.168.1.104 port 5432" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

I am not sure that it is the best way, which is why I am posting here.  I would love to learn the best way to do this on Mac.

I did get this warning, though I don't know that it actually flushed any rules:

```
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pfctl: pf already enabled
```

From the man page, `-f` is just telling it to parse the file, which I am sending in via `stdin`.

Any discussion, improvements, or hints would be great!